# How to put a hyperlink inside a text in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to put a clickable text inside a PHP text, how to do that?

this is my code, the link should be in (click here)

```
<p><?php _e("some text click here some text", 'var');?></p>
```

Comment: Are you intending for the text to  be a hyperlink?

Comment: yes, just the (click here) part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use seemingly Wordpress so this is not a php function but a Wordpress function _e ();

Here is a link and you can see how to do it with Wordpress:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114201/html-inside-or-e-language-translation-string

But if you want to do that only with php, then an echo with your link in the text as well as in HTML will suffice:

```
<?php echo 'This is a link <a href="https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/">click here</a> for more.';
```

But you can also write a function yourself that works like Wordpress:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/

Use the simple form or break out the markup

```
<?php echo __( 'Please read <a href="https://goo.gl">this</a>', 'example-domain' );
```

or, but all not good by translation

```
<?php _e( 'This is a link <a href="https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165357/how-to-make-a-text-with-hyperlink-translatable-in-wordpress">click here</a> for more', 'example-domain' );
```

break out the html, try this one and you can more shorten this but for understand

```
$anchor = esc_html_x( 'Google', 'link text for google.com', 'txt-domain' );
$domain = esc_url( __( 'google.com', 'txt-domain' ) );  
$link   = sprintf( '<a href="https://%s">%s</a>', $domain, $anchor );

 /* translators: 1 is a link with text "Google" and URL google.com */
echo sprintf( esc_html__( 'Use %1$s to search.', 'example-domain' ), $link );
```

The web is full of stuff:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165357/how-to-make-a-text-with-hyperlink-translatable-in-wordpress